# Java Object class MYSTERY

Tags: java, class, object

While Porting a Game I come to a below statement

```
Object o = new Object[]{"A","B"};
```

It's really weird!

But when I try the same with "String" then compiler report me an Error msg

> String s = new String[] {"A", "B", "C"};   Error: Type mismatch:
>   cannot convert from String[] to String

Can you please reveal the Mystery of it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a trivial error in your code. The fact that **every class extends Object** makes the error more difficult to find.

Since every class (including arrays) extends `Object`, conversion from `A[]` to `Object` is possible.

You wrote `int i = new int[]` but that's a mistake, you should have written `int[] i`.

Probably. `Object a = new Object[]` is not what you wanted to do.

Comment: Since every class (including arrays) extends Object; and all we know that Base class pointer can points to Derived class

Answer (score 3):

In `Java`, Array is an `Object` too. So you can do

```
Object o = new Object[]{"A","B"};
```

or

```
Object o = new String[]{"A","B"};// But array of String not a String
```

or

```
Object o = new int[]{1,2};// But array of int not an int
```

Answer (score 2):

An "Array" of objects is also an object. But an "Array" of ints is NOT an int. 
    i.e, an int reference cannot point to an Array but an object reference can.

```
    Object[] obj = new Object[5];// works fine
```

Answer (score 1):

An object can be anything. It can be an array, it can be an single variable.

```
Object O = new Object[]{"S","A"};
```

- When you define object you can type cast it to your desired data type.
- You can not assign an array of a data type to a single variable of that 'same' datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Every array is an `Object[]` **AND** an `Object`, that's why the following are equally valid:

```
Object[] o = new Object[]{"A","B"};
Object o = new Object[]{"A","B"};
```

However a `String[]` **is not** a `String` (and vice-versa) and a `int[]` **is not** a `int` (and vice-versa).
Indeed, you would blend primitives with objects in this latter case.